# Mapbox-gl markers on map is not in the right location

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I'm currently working on a react app which contains a map, this map will require markers on it. Currently I have the map and I've styled it the way I want it to be but when I plot a marker, the marker is way off the actual point in which it should be. I'm using mapbox-gl as the documentation for react-mapbox-gl seems to lack.

It should be plotted in Denver, CO but its not, some instances when fully zoomed out it outside of the map component.

````
    console.log("Map props", props)

    const [map, setMap] = useState(null)
    const mapContainerRef = useRef(null)
    let mapboxgl = require('mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js');

    useEffect(() => {
        const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
          container: mapContainerRef.current,
          style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
          center: [-104.9876, 39.7405],
          zoom: 7,
        });

        let marker = new mapboxgl.Marker({color: 'blue'})
                .setLngLat([-104.9876, 39.7405])
                .addTo(map)
    }, []);


    return (
        <div ref={el => (mapContainerRef.current = el)} style={{height: '50em', width: '100%'}} />
    ) 

}```

Before anyone says anything I have the token within my code currently so that is not the issue.
````

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this by switching to react-mapbox-gl instead, then using the following code to put a small circle on the map instead.

```
<Map 
    style="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9"
    containerStyle={{
         height: "calc(100vh - 130px)",
         width: "100%"
    }}
    center={[-0.5225869881734102, 53.235052086599545]}
    zoom={[16]}
>

    {/* Map Marker */}
    <Layer
        type="symbol"
        layout={{ "icon-image": "circle-15", "icon-size": 1.5 }}>
        <Feature
          coordinates={[-0.5371284484863282, 53.23427159260936]}            
        />
    </Layer>
</Map>
```

I continued to mess about with the react-mapbox-gl context api and managed to replicate the exact mapbox marker example with this using the following code.

```
<MapContext.Consumer>
     {(map) => {
         let mapboxgl = require('mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js');

          var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker()
              .setLngLat([12.550343, 55.665957])
              .addTo(map);
          }}
</MapContext.Consumer>
```

Removing the issue totally.

Comment: Hey, could you show a pic of how the result looks like this? Is <Feature> a self created component? Could you look into this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63437137/alternative-for-pointannotation